# How to get first day of the month from current Date(java.util.Date)?

Tags: java, date, datetime

Want to get the first day of month from current date.

To get that I'm doing with org.apache.commons.lang3.time.DateUtils to return in below format

```
DateUtils.truncate(new Date(), 2);
```

this is returning expected output like below:

```
Fri Jul 01 00:00:00 IST 2022
```

Is any other way to get the 1st day of the current month with the same above date time format?

Comment: You should stop using `Date`, for it's obsolete. Use classes from the `java.time` package. In your case probably `ZonedDateTime`.

Comment: Or possibly `LocalDate`, depending on how you want to handle time zones... (The requirements are really unclear at the moment.)

Comment: "...with the same above date time format" - Note that formats are a matter of string representation, i.e. they depend on a couple of things like timezone, locale etc. A date object (ideally one of the java.time versions) never has a _format_, it just represents a point in time.

Comment: `String output = YearMonth.now(ZONE).atDay(1).atStartOfDay(ZONE).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz y", Locale.ROOT))`. Set `ZONE` to your desired time zone. When I set it to `ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata")`, I got `Fri Jul 01 00:00:00 IST 2022`.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `java.time.LocalDate`.

```java
LocalDate myLocalDate = LocalDate.now();
myLocalDate.withDayOfMonth(1));
```

Alternatively, use `YearMonth`.

```
YearMonth myYearMonth = YearMonth.now() ;
LocalDate myLocalDate = myYearMonth.atDay( 1 ) ;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are in jdk8, you can use `java.time.LocalDate`.

```
LocalDate now = LocalDate.now();
LocalDate res = now.with(TemporalAdjusters.firstDayOfMonth());
System.out.println(res);
```

If the result type you want is Date.

```
ZoneId zone = ZoneId.systemDefault();
Instant instant = localDate.atStartOfDay().atZone(zone).toInstant();
return Date.from(instant);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you still want to use older Date library then :

```
        Calendar calendar =Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,1);
        System.out.println(calendar.getTime());
```

Output:(time zone varies based on your locale)

```
Fri Jul 01 08:54:39 BST 2022
```